# PHP find ancestry of current object ($this) and method

Tags: php, class, oop

In any given context in OOP, `$this` refers to the current class.  However if the current class extends a previous class which in turn extended a previous class etc., it can get a little difficult to trace.  I say this because I'm using Magento and it's a brain stretcher.

My goal is to trace this information and then hopefully get
a) the location of each parent class in the system and 
b) the methods of each class

How would I do this?  My thought is that I could use get_included_files() as well and create a method in the core class which, if called, would tell me where any given method is located - authoritatively - in which file, and with respect to the "last method instance" that extended it.

I will be happy to post the tool created on this thread

so if you had this code

```
function myFirstMethod(){
    //call this tool
    Mage::log($tools->trace('someOtherMethod'));
    //this was already here
    $this->someOtherMethod();  //where is it? has it been extended? That's what I want to determine
}
```

Comment: Can you use `get_parent_class()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php ?

Comment: you can find out the current class by simply using `__CLASS__` magic constant [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: Thanks Maximus, yes, but I need to get all parent classes, and all their methods.  Building from that, I can determine which instance of say ->myMethod( ) trumps, which will then help me navigate through the code.  This is also based on the assumption that at least in Magento one file contains one class, and I can map it that way.  I'm wanting to create a tool which will create a GUI that says "The following method (myMethod) is located in /app/code/core/blah/blah.php in class Mage_Etc_Etc on line 738" (the line # would be total icing on the cake)

Comment: Well you can call get_parent_class() in a loop, feeding the result of each call back in again until you get a false returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet uses [get_class](https://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) and [get_parent_class](https://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) to go up the inheritance tree of an instance:

```
<?php

class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {
  function trace() {
    $cls = get_class($this);

    while ($cls !== FALSE) {
      echo $cls. "\n\t with methods: " . implode(', ', get_class_methods($cls))  . "\n";
      $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($cls);
      echo "\t" . $reflectionClass->getFileName() . "\n";

      $cls = get_parent_class($cls);
    }
  }
}

(new C())->trace();
```

which outputs the following output on my machine:

```
C
 with methods: trace
/tmp/stuff.php
B
 with methods: 
 /tmp/stuff.php
A
 with methods: 
 /tmp/stuff.php
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for, now if I can specify the methods of each class, I can then determine the "last instance" of extended classes.  Combining with get_included_files( ), I believe I can create a tracer which as I'm finding out in Magento would be very helpful :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to include more information. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all involved here, and I hope this gives the seed for a good tracing tool (if it's not already developed):

```
function trace() {
    //you can modify this, this is hard coded
    $this->_root='/home/vagrant/commoncart/';

    $cls = get_class($this);
    $i=0;
    $methodMap=array();
    $classMap=array();
    //we are ascending UPwards
    while ($cls !== FALSE) {

        $i++;
        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($cls);
        $file=$reflectionClass->getFileName();

        $classMap[$cls]=$file;

        if($a=get_class_methods($cls)) foreach($a as $method){
            if(!empty($methodMap[$method])){
                $methodMap[$method]['override']=true;
                $methodMap[$method]['overridden'][]=$cls; //
            }else{
                $methodMap[$method]=array(
                    'class'=>$cls,
                    'file'=>str_replace($this->_root,'',$file),
                    'line'=>'undefined', //this would be great to have, probably need to read the file and parse it once..
                );
            }
        }

        $cls = get_parent_class($cls);
        if($i>5)break;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($classMap);
    print_r($methodMap);
    exit('done');
}
```